# How can I set the return value in my unit test of a boto3 client call that calls on client.get_parameters_by_path()?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, boto3

I have the following code, where I am trying to mock the call to `client.get_parameters_by_path`.

```
`#util/config.py`

import boto3

def get_parameters():
    client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name=AWS_REGION)
    try:
        res = client.get_parameters_by_path(Path=path, Recursive=True, WithDecryption=True) <--- trying to mock
        breakpoint()
    except ClientError as e:
        'not important'
```

Here is my code to mock the call:

```
@mock.patch("util.config.boto3")
def test_get_parameters(mock_session_class):
    mock_boto3_object = mock.Mock()
    mock_client = mock.Mock()
    mock_client.get_parameters_by_path.return_value = {'Name': 'string'}
    mock_boto3_object.client.return_value = mock_client
    mock_session_class.return_value = mock_boto3_object
    get_parameters('something', 'something2')
```

But where I set the `breakpoint()` when I `print(res)`, I get:

```
<MagicMock name='boto3.client().get_parameters_by_path()' id='140559375411600'>
```

But I am expecting the return value `{'Name': 'string'}` that I set in my unit test to be printed.

Any ideas where I have gone slightly wrong?